# ruby on rails. Не отражается раскрывающиеся меню Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails

Изучаю рельсы по книге Майкла Харта. Сейчас - создается надо создать раскрывающиеся меню для зарегистрированного пользователя. Как в книге должно быть
[image: Образец из книги]

А имеется по факту - только надпись Account, которая не реагирует ни на курсор, ни на клик.
[image: То, что есть]
 Код файла _header

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Код файла application.js. Здесь я пробовал записывать и через //= и через require ("").start(). Эффект один

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//=require bootstrap
```

Код файла custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
#logo {
ﬂoat: left;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 1.7em;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding-top: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

body {
padding-top: 60px;
}
section {
overﬂow: auto;
}
textarea {
resize: vertical;
}
.center {
text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3em;
letter-spacing: -2px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
h2 {
font-size: 1.2em;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: normal;
color: #777;
}
p {
font-size: 1.1em;
line-height: 1.7em;
}

@mixin box_sizing {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.debug_dump {
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 45px;
@include box_sizing;
}

/* подвал сайта*/
footer {
margin-top: 45px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
color: #777;
}
footer a {
color: #555;
}
footer a:hover {
color: #222;
}
footer small {
ﬂoat: left;
}

footer ul {
ﬂoat: right;
list-style: none;
}
footer ul li {
ﬂoat: left;
margin-left: 15px;
}

/* боковая панель */
aside {
section.user_info {
margin-top: 20px;
}
section {
padding: 10px 0;
margin-top: 20px;
&:first-child {
border: 0;
padding-top: 0;
}
span {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
font-size: 1.4em;
text-align: left;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
}
}
.gravatar {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.gravatar_edit {
margin-top: 15px;
}

/* формы */
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
@include box_sizing;
}
input {
height: auto !important;
}

#error_explanation {
  color: red;
ul {
color: red;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
}
.field_with_errors {
@extend .has-error;
.form-control {
color: $state-danger-text;
}
}
```

Ну и для полноты Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'rails-controller-testing'

gem 'bcrypt'
```

Огромная просьба помочь разобраться, так как что не работает и почему не подключается - я так и не смог разобраться

Comment: По какому изданию Хартла занимаетесь? Там точно 6-е рельсы у него в книге?

Comment: @Василиса нет, у него версия 4.2.*, но я подумал, что надо попробовать на последней версии, все равно с этими же проблемами столкнусь при переходе на них

Comment: И ещё у него четко написано, что работать всё будет только и исключительно при соблюдении всех версий, указанных в его гемфайле. Между 4-ми и 6-ми рельсами лежит пропасть, особенно в части работы с JS. Очень вам рекомендую пройти этот туториал на 4-х рельсах (если вам критично проходить его на русском), или переключиться на https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-4th-edition-tutorial/beginning, пока оно доступно бесплатно (если понимаете на английском)

Comment: В любом случае, пользы от туториала на 4-й версии будет очень много, дальше вы сможете уже разбираться с тем, что поменялось в 5-й и 6-й

Comment: @Василиса наверное так и сделаю, что бы исключить дальнейшие расхождения версий.НО если брать 6 рельсы - как тогда подключить это выпадающие меню?

Comment: У вас как с английским и знанием js в целом? Ссылка на доку пойдёт на инглише или лучше на русском? Я сама с 6-ми ещё не работала, но суть в том, что там изменился механизм подключения js в проекте, sprockets заменили на webpacker, а jquery по дефолту выпилили, насколько я помню

Comment: @Василиса лучше конечно на русском. с js не знаком, рельсы - это первый фреймворк для веб разработки, до этого была только Java, ну и сам Ruby

Comment: https://medium.com/@alx_khramov/webpacker-d68d0996c3b1 - вот то немногое, что есть на русском. В 6-х рельсах webpacker идёт по умолчанию, sprockets убрали. Но вам в таких тонкостях может быть и рано пока досконально разбираться.

Comment: Если хотите серьёзно работать на рельсах, то очень рекомендую прокачать английский до того уровня, чтобы без проблем читать документацию. По рельсам современной доки на русском мало, здесь на стаке тоже всё грустно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы изменили версию rails с 4 (для которой написан учебник) на 6. Так просто это не заработает, слишком много всего изменилось в рельсах за это время. Что надо сделать:

- изменить в Gemfile версию рельсов на нужную. Проверить, что версии всех остальных гемов указаны верно. Проще всего целиком скопировать Gemfile из учебника
- удалить Gemfile.lock
- запустить `bundle install`

Таким образом вы заново построите все зависимости и залочите их версии во вновь сгенерированном Gemfile.lock. Он вообще нужен для того, чтобы у всех разработчиков на проекте, а также в продакшне, версии всех гемов были одинаковые

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как тогда установить в системе корректную версию? Потому что при bundle install выдает The bundle currently has rails locked at 6.0.0. Удалил через gem uninstall, установил 4.2.0. Но при этом команда rails --version выдает 6,0,0, а команда gem list --local показывет rails 4.2.0. Система windows 10

Comment: @славагудзенко обновила ответ